# How to vectorize fourier series partial sum in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, fft, vectorization, series

Given the Fourier series coefficients `a[n]` and `b[n]` (for cosines and sines respectively) of a function with period `T` and `t` an equally spaced interval the following code will evaluate the partial sum for all points in interval `t` (`a`,`b`,`t` are all `numpy` arrays). It is clarified that len(t) <> len(a).

```
yn=ones(len(t))*a[0]
for n in range(1,len(a)):
    yn=yn+(a[n]*cos(2*pi*n*t/T)-b[n]*sin(2*pi*n*t/T))
```

My question is: Can this for loop be vectorized?

Comment: Typo in your example, surely you mean `len(a)`?

Comment: @Ahmed Fasih, that's correct of course, corrected,thank you.

Comment: Why don't you just use the inverse Fourier transform? If you want to interpolate, you can pad the high frequencies with zeros.

Comment: @Dirklinux, I just prefer to do it myself, it gives me better understanding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one vectorized approach making use [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) to create the `2D` array version of cosine/sine input : `2*pi*n*t/T` and then using `matrix-multiplication` with [`np.dot`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) for the `sum-reduction` -

```
r = np.arange(1,len(a))
S = 2*np.pi*r[:,None]*t/T
cS = np.cos(S)
sS = np.sin(S)
out = a[1:].dot(cS) - b[1:].dot(sS) + a[0]
```

**Further performance boost**

For further boost, we can make use of [`numexpr` module](https://github.com/pydata/numexpr/wiki/Numexpr-Users-Guide) to compute those trignometric steps -

```
import numexpr as ne
cS = ne.evaluate('cos(S)')
sS = ne.evaluate('sin(S)')
```

**Runtime test -**

Approaches -

```
def original_app(t,a,b,T):
    yn=np.ones(len(t))*a[0]
    for n in range(1,len(a)):
        yn=yn+(a[n]*np.cos(2*np.pi*n*t/T)-b[n]*np.sin(2*np.pi*n*t/T))
    return yn

def vectorized_app(t,a,b,T):    
    r = np.arange(1,len(a))
    S = (2*np.pi/T)*r[:,None]*t
    cS = np.cos(S)
    sS = np.sin(S)
    return a[1:].dot(cS) - b[1:].dot(sS) + a[0]

def vectorized_app_v2(t,a,b,T):    
    r = np.arange(1,len(a))
    S = (2*np.pi/T)*r[:,None]*t
    cS = ne.evaluate('cos(S)')
    sS = ne.evaluate('sin(S)')
    return a[1:].dot(cS) - b[1:].dot(sS) + a[0]
```

Also, including  function `PP` from @Paul Panzer's post.

Timings -

```
In [22]: # Setup inputs
    ...: n = 10000
    ...: t = np.random.randint(0,9,(n))
    ...: a = np.random.randint(0,9,(n))
    ...: b = np.random.randint(0,9,(n))
    ...: T = 3.45
    ...: 

In [23]: print np.allclose(original_app(t,a,b,T), vectorized_app(t,a,b,T))
    ...: print np.allclose(original_app(t,a,b,T), vectorized_app_v2(t,a,b,T))
    ...: print np.allclose(original_app(t,a,b,T), PP(t,a,b,T))
    ...: 
True
True
True

In [25]: %timeit original_app(t,a,b,T)
    ...: %timeit vectorized_app(t,a,b,T)
    ...: %timeit vectorized_app_v2(t,a,b,T)
    ...: %timeit PP(t,a,b,T)
    ...: 
1 loops, best of 3: 6.49 s per loop
1 loops, best of 3: 6.24 s per loop
1 loops, best of 3: 1.54 s per loop
1 loops, best of 3: 1.96 s per loop
```

Comment: Thank you. You assumed that a and t are of the same length, which is not what I had in mind; but it is easy to take care of that. I will post the modified code. I have not yet studied the optimizations. I have also noticed that you changed the tag from fourier to fft. I beg to differ.

Comment: @NameOfTheRose Well the original code had `for n in range(1,len(t)):`, which was later changed to use `len(a)`. So, I was needed to edit `r` part to use `len(a)` instead. Edited accordingly.

Comment: My mistake then, I apologize. As you have already edited your post, there is no reason to post the modified code myself, it is a very simple modification any way

Answer (score 2):

Can't beat numexpr, but if it's not available we can save on the transcendentals (testing and benchmarking code heavily based on @Divakar's code in case you didn't notice ;-) ):

```
import numpy as np
from timeit import timeit

def PP(t,a,b,T):
    CS = np.empty((len(t), len(a)-1), np.complex)
    CS[...] = np.exp(2j*np.pi*(t[:, None])/T)
    np.cumprod(CS, axis=-1, out=CS)
    return a[1:].dot(CS.T.real) - b[1:].dot(CS.T.imag) + a[0]

def original_app(t,a,b,T):
    yn=np.ones(len(t))*a[0]
    for n in range(1,len(a)):
        yn=yn+(a[n]*np.cos(2*np.pi*n*t/T)-b[n]*np.sin(2*np.pi*n*t/T))
    return yn

def vectorized_app(t,a,b,T):    
    r = np.arange(1,len(a))
    S = 2*np.pi*r[:,None]*t/T
    cS = np.cos(S)
    sS = np.sin(S)
    return a[1:].dot(cS) - b[1:].dot(sS) + a[0]

n = 1000
t = 2000
t = np.random.randint(0,9,(t))
a = np.random.randint(0,9,(n))
b = np.random.randint(0,9,(n))
T = 3.45


print(np.allclose(original_app(t,a,b,T), vectorized_app(t,a,b,T)))
print(np.allclose(original_app(t,a,b,T), PP(t,a,b,T)))

print('{:18s} {:9.6f}'.format('orig', timeit(lambda: original_app(t,a,b,T), number=10)/10))
print('{:18s} {:9.6f}'.format('Divakar no numexpr', timeit(lambda: vectorized_app(t,a,b,T), number=10)/10))
print('{:18s} {:9.6f}'.format('PP', timeit(lambda: PP(t,a,b,T), number=10)/10))
```

Prints:

```
True
True
orig                0.166903
Divakar no numexpr  0.179617
PP                  0.060817
```

Btw. if delta `t` divides `T` one can potentially save more, or even run the full fft and discard what's too much.

Comment: Your comment about transcendentals makes me hope Numpy gets [`sincos`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/2626) soon!

Comment: @AhmedFasih interesting. Thanks for sharing the link. I didn't even know `sin` and `cos` were machine instructions ...

Comment: Smart thought with that complex array creation!

Comment: @Divakar thanks. Obviously accumulated error becomes a concern if the `cumprod` gets very long...

Comment: Both answers are of course valid and achieve great speedups. This one's performance is very close to the numexpr version. It should be the accepted answer if numexpr is not available

Answer (score 0):

*This is not really another answer but a comment on @Paul Panzer's one, written as an answer because I needed to post some code. If there is a way to post propely formatted code in a comment please advice.*

Inspired by @Paul Panzer  `cumprod` idea, I came up with the following:

```
an = ones((len(a)-1,len(te)))*2j*pi*te/T
CS = exp(cumsum(an,axis=0))
out = (a[1:].dot(CS.real) - b[1:].dot(CS.imag)) + a[0]
```

Although it seems properly vectorized and produces correct results, its performance is miserable. It is not only much slower than the `cumprod`, which is expected as `len(a)-1` exponentiations more are made,  but 50% slower than the original unvectorized version. What is the cause of this poor performance?

Comment: My guess would be 1) as you suggest, the different numbers of `exp` calls. Please note that the difference is of order `len(a) x len(t)` as the number of elements of `an` is  the product, not the sum of its dimensions. 2) memory layout: in your original semi-vectorised code all variables are presumably contiguous in memory and therefore liable to profit from optimised code which the interleaved `.real` and `.imag` arrays cannot use.

Comment: @Paul Panzer, thank you, my (naive) intuition was performance similar to Divakar's 1st version. Are you still surprised some times by numpy's performance?

Comment: More impressed than surprised. They are really making it substantially better with every release. But if you meant do I sometimes get the "this should be faster than that" gut feeling wrong? Yes, actually quite often.